# Return all paths and cost between two nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I already find all paths between two nodes, but I need their cost(weight).

```
CREATE (a:Location {name: 'A'}),
(b:Location {name: 'B'}),
(c:Location {name: 'C'}),
(h:Location {name: 'H'}),
 (j:Location {name: 'J'}),
(a)-[:ROAD {cost: 50}]->(b),
(a)-[:ROAD {cost: 50}]->(c),
(c)-[:ROAD {cost: 40}]->(j),
(j)-[:ROAD {cost: 30}]->(h),
(h)-[:ROAD {cost: 50}]->(b); 

MATCH p=(o{name:"A"})-[r*]->(x{name:"B"})
RETURN [x in nodes(p) | id(x)]
```

output

```
╒═════════════════════╕
│"list_path"          │
╞═════════════════════╡
│["A","C","J","H","B"]│
├─────────────────────┤
│["A","B"]            │
└─────────────────────┘
```

expected output

```
path                                  cost
1. [A,C,J,H,B]               [0,50,90,130,180]
2. [A,B]                        [0,50]
```

Here is my query. I use node names for start and end. actually, I need to use nodeID

query I tried

```
MATCH p=(o)-[r*]->(x)
WHERE ID(o) =13 AND ID(x) = 14
RETURN [x in nodes(p) | id(x)] as list_path, [y in r | y.cost] as cost
```

output

```
╒════════════════╤═════════════╕
│"list_path"     │"cost"       │
╞════════════════╪═════════════╡
│[13,15,22,20,14]│[50,40,30,50]│
├────────────────┼─────────────┤
│[13,14]         │[50]         │
└────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

**I need cost start with zero  like([0,50,90,130,180])**

Answer (score 2):

To start off, you can just prepend a zero to the cost array. Next, I create a list of array that are used to calculate the cumulative sum of cost along the way using the `apoc.coll.sum` function. Probably there are more options how to calculate the cumulative sum of elements in a list, but this is simplest I could think of:

```
MATCH p=(o)-[r*0..]->(x)
WHERE ID(o) =13 AND ID(x) = 14
// Prepend a zero
WITH [x in nodes(p) | id(x)] as list_path, [0] + [y in r | y.cost] as cost_path
// Create list of lists 
RETURN list_path, [i in range(1, size(cost_path)) | apoc.coll.sum(cost_path[..i])] as cost, apoc.coll.sum(cost_path) as total_cost
ORDER BY total_cost DESC
```

Output:

```
╒═══════════╤═══════════════════════════╕
│"list_path"│"cost"                     │
╞═══════════╪═══════════════════════════╡
│[0,1]      │[0.0,50.0]                 │
├───────────┼───────────────────────────┤
│[0,2,4,3,1]│[0.0,50.0,90.0,120.0,170.0]│
└───────────┴───────────────────────────┘
```

You can convert the elements in the cost array to integer if that is what you prefer.

Comment: how to sort total cost 'ORDER BY cost DECS'?